# Using i18n + handlebars in an express app, but not to generate output html, how to localize?

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization, handlebars.js

I have an Express app in which I want to use handlebars to generate localised templated emails to be sent out. The problem is that handlebars requires a globally registered helper to translate items inside the `.hbs` files, while I need to use a construct such as `app.use(i18n.init)` to make sure my `__` function translates according to the right locale in the context of the current request. Setting a locale globally will lead to concurrency issues.

The only 'solutions' (which aren't because they don't solve my problem) I found consist of using handlebars middleware to output html using Express, but that is not what I want to do. I want to generate content that's completely independent from what Express sends back to the client.

This is what I am currently doing, which obviously isn't the way to do it

```
const i18n = require("i18n")
const Handlebars = require('handlebars')
i18n.configure({
  directory: './i18n',
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  objectNotation: true,
  syncFiles: true
})

Handlebars.registerHelper('i18n',
  function (str) {
    if(!str) return str
    return i18n.__(str)
  }
)
```

to be used as

```
<td>
  {{i18n "title"}}
</td>
```

A possible solution is to do the translations in code by calling `i18n.__({phrase: "someText", locale: locale})` but I would like to keep this inside the template.

How can I make sure handlebars uses the i18n instance bound to the Express response object?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a different handlebars helper

```
   phrase: function (str) {
        if (!str) return str
        let translated = i18n.__(str);
        console.log('translated', translated);
        return translated
    },
```

then on your html do use it like with "phrase"

`{{phrase 'login'}}`

i tried it and it works.